# how to load image tkinter at runtime?

Tags: python, image, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I am trying to browse image file and load it in label using tkinter. I am unable to load the new browsed image. I am just trying to show preview of the image in the label right now it is loading full image hence only some part of the image is captured. How can I reduce the image size that is loaded in the label so full image is previewed label.
source code:

```
root = Tk()
def browsefunc():
    filename = fd.askopenfilename()
    print(filename)
    ss=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename))
    panel.configure(image=ss)

file=r"C:/img.jpg"
img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(file))
browsebutton = Button(root, text="Browse", command=browsefunc, justify ="center")
panel = Label(root,height="500",width="500", image = img,justify="left")
panel.pack(side = "top", expand = "yes")

browsebutton.pack(side="bottom")
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you are not keeping a reference for your image in your method, that *might* lead to that, your image not appear at all.

About resizing, you can use [PIL.Image.resize()](http://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.x/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)

```
def browsefunc():
    filename = fd.askopenfilename()
    print(filename)
    si = Image.open(filename)
    h = panel.winfo_height() # label's current height
    w = panel.winfo_width() # label's current width
    si = si.resize((h,w)) 
    ss = ImageTk.PhotoImage(si)
    panel.image=ss # keeping a reference!!
    panel.configure(image=ss)
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but I am getting error "can't invoke "winfo" command: application has been destroyed"

Comment: Given code in your question shouldn't produce that. It seems like, your label is not reachable/destroyed at that point.

Comment: it is working initially but when i try to  get image using button click file browser the image is loading but applying resize throws error "unknown resampling filter" i used resize(500,500)

Comment: Note the second set of parentheses. `resize((500,500))`.